# PHP & SMARTY => Can't access appended variables in .tpl file

Tags: php, html, smarty

I am trying to display error messages by assigning the SMARTY variable `$error` in the form of:

```
function validate1() {
  $error['title'] = "Title contains illegal characters...";
  $this->smarty->append('error', $error);
}
function validate2() {
  $error['time'] = "Please enter a time in 12 hour clock (12:30 PM) format.";
  $this->smarty->append('error', $error);
}
```

My HTML looks like:

```
<p class="message-error">{$error['title']}</p>
<p class="message-error">{$error['time']}</p>
```

I had recently been using the code below, which works; is there any way that I can modify the first block of code to work the same as the code below?

```
$error['title'] = "Title contains illegal characters...";
$error['time'] = "Please enter a time in 12 hour clock (12:30 PM) format.";
$this->smarty->assign("error", $error);
```

Comment: Not sure, but it's impossible with using `append`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you define the array this way and include the merge option (3rd param to `append()`)

```
function validate1() {
  $error = array('title' => "Title contains illegal characters...");
  $this->smarty->append('error', $error, TRUE);
  // -------------------------------------^^^^
}
```

**EDIT** Forgot to include the merge parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Read smarty [manual](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.tpl#language.variables.assoc.arrays), correct syntax for associative arrays is:

```
{$error.title}
```

Comment: I think they're equivalent, but thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Not sure they are equivalent, but I can't check it right now. Btw, have you tried look into [smarty debugging console](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/chapter.debugging.console.tpl), do you see $error array there?